# jquery-bootgrid How to combine two data value in one same column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

now i have two idea to combine two data in one column,but something wrong when i using my way to solve.

The first way sure wrong,because cant just put + to combine them

```
<th data-column-id="NO_ID" >N0</th> 
change to--->  <th data-column-id="NO_ID + USR_ID" >N0</th>
```

This is the second way,cannot use because i have already using one formatters call commands to show button,i cant make both commands and test to work

```
<script>
    formatters: 
        {
            "commands": function(column, row)
            {
                return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.NO_ID + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button>" 
            }
             "test": function(column, row)
            {
                return "NO_ID","USR_ID";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the same problem
seem like need to change the bootgrid.js file....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make both work this way:

```
 $('#yourBootGridTableId').bootgrid({
    formatters: {
        "commands": function(column, row){
            return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.NO_ID + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button>";
        },
         "test": function(column, row){
            return "<div>" + row.NO_ID + ", " + row.USR_ID + "</div>";
        }
    },
    rowCount: [5, 10, 25],
    caseSensitive: false,
    selection: false,
    multiSelect: false,    //Other bootgrid options...
});
```